# DataTable sorting does not sort properly after merging

Tags: c#, sorting, datatable

I have 2 DataTables that I'm combining using the `.Merge` method.

The column type for the 2 DataTables are `System.Decimal`.
But it does not seem to sort properly. The data for the 1st DataTable will be sorted first and then subsequently the data from the 2nd DataTable.

[image]

So if you see the picture above, it will display the 1st DataTable data, and then 2nd DataTable, sorted by the start time.

If I reverse the sorting, it will sort the 2nd DataTable data in descending order then the 1st DataTable will appear.

[image]

This is the code for my sorting

```
DataView dv = new DataView(dataTableResult);
dv.Sort = string.Format("{0} {1}", ViewState["sortexp"].ToString(), 
GetSortDirection());
return dv;
```

`ViewState["sortexp"]` contains Start Time in this case, and `GetSortDirection` is either "ASC" or "DESC".

My query:

```
select  ....
        to_number(to_char([start_field],'hh24mi')) as start_time, 
        to_number(to_char([end_field], 'hh24mi')) as end_time,
        ...
from    [table]
where   [condition]
```

and another one I am getting the result from webservice and populate the datarow manually.

```
foreach (DTResult dtr in result)
{
    DataRow dr = dtTable2.NewRow();
    ...
    dr["start_time"] = Decimal.Parse(dtr.start_time.Replace(":", ""));
    dr["end_time"] = Decimal.Parse(dtr.end_time.Replace(":", ""));
    ...
    dtTable2.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

And the merging code

```
dataTableResult.Merge(dtTable1);
dataTableResult.Merge(dtTable2);
```

Defintion for dtTable column:

```
...
dtTable2.Columns.Add("start_time", typeof(decimal));
dtTable2.Columns.Add("end_time", typeof(decimal));
...
```

How to solve the issue?

Comment: You probably think that all the Fields type is `decimal`. There's the chance that the `Start Time` field (or all fields) of those tables is of type `string`.

Comment: I've already converted it to Decimal too.

Comment: Yes, well, what is `dtTable`? And its fields **object** type? This sorting result is quite probably coming from strings evaluation. Check twice, while debugging.

Comment: I''l update the definition for dtTable ,please take a look.

Comment: @Jimi Except strings would sort (DESC) `"800", "1600", "1400", "1200"`

Comment: @Rufus L  Yes, that's true, and it would be `"1200", "1400", "1600", "800"` in ascending order. This order *may* depend on the local language settings (and/or on non visible chars). For sure this can't be reproduced with decimals. Of course the two tables can't have a different object data types, they won't merge. Strings are the only thing that came to mind. At least the OP posted all the object definitions now. Anyway, testing this, I couldn't reproduce this behaviour, using decimals in any way.

Comment: Btw, have you tried to merge the two tables directly: `dtTable1.Merge(dtTable2)`? Then use the `DefaultView` as the DataSource of a DataGridView (or similar) after sorting it: `dtTable1.DefaultView.Sort = $"{dtTable1.Columns[0].ColumnName} ASC, {dtTable1.Columns[1].ColumnName} ASC";`.

Comment: @Jimi, tried your suggestion but it does not work.

Comment: Allright. Have you really checked, in debug mode, the merged table content `=> dataTableResult -> Rows -> Result View -> [0] -> ItemArray`, to eyeball the actual content of the rows before setting the DataSource of something? If the values are not all of the same type, you should see it there. If they're all the same object data type (decimal, here), I don't know why they shouldn't sort correctly.

Comment: I debug and I found out it is due to dataTableResult creates separate column instead of combining with the 1st datatable schema definition. I'll post as an answer to elaborate this in more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging, I found out that it is due to `dataTableResult.Merge(dtTable2);` command creates new columns in `dataTableResult`, so that the number of columns become double.

So the content of the `dataTableResult` is something like the following:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|Rows              | start_time | end_time | start_time | end_time |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|0                 | 1200       | 1400     | NULL       | NULL     | --> 1st data table merge
|1                 | 800        | 1000     | 800        | 1000     | --> 2nd data table merge
|2                 | 1400       | 1600     | 1400       | 1600     | --> 2nd data table merge
|3                 | 1600       | 1800     | 1600       | 1800     | --> 2nd data table merge
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The column name is just for illustration, since I cannot see the actual column name. So once the 2nd datatable is merged, it creates new columns. The new columns for the 1st datatable contains NULL. And the column content for the 2nd datatable will be repeated (like both start_time columns will have the same value).
It's quite weird though.

So here is how I solve the problem:

In the `dataTableResult`, I will define all the columns using capital letters as the column name. For some reason, the previous query is using normal letter and this causes it to double.

```
dataTableResult.Columns.Add("START_TIME", typeof(decimal));
dataTableResult.Columns.Add("END_TIME", typeof(decimal));
```

Then in the Database Query, I will also use capital letters as the column name alias

```
select  ....
        to_number(to_char([start_field],'hh24mi')) as START_TIME, 
        to_number(to_char([end_field], 'hh24mi')) as END_TIME,
        ...
from    [table]
where   [condition]
```

And similarly for the 2nd DataTable

```
dtTable2.Columns.Add("START_TIME", typeof(decimal));
dtTable2.Columns.Add("END_TIME", typeof(decimal));
```

By doing it this way, when calling `dataTableResult.Merge(dtTable2);`, the resulting datatable will not have duplicated columns, and the sorting issue is fixed.